# Is it possible to publish an applied paper using a new method followed by a methodology paper explaining it?

Tags: publications, research-process

I am presently working on some applied research as part of a research practicum and have come up with with some new (*potentially*) publication-worthy methods.

Is it possible to publish the results using these new methods (along with others) in a applied paper and later work on writing the methods paper which dives deeper into the method and gives it a more thorough treatment?

For context, I am working in the field of statistics.

Answer (score 1):

I think it unlikely that a paper that didn't explain its methodology in some detail could be publishable. You might be forced by this to combine the papers into one.

If you really want two papers or the full results would make it too long, you might consider writing a detailed paper about the methodology and including only "preliminary results" using it in the first paper and a follow up with a more complete treatment.

Even a pure methodology paper with no hint at applications might have some difficulty getting published. The response might be "So what?".

But a paper that professes to give results without the reader's (reviewers) knowing the methodology by which those results are obtained just seems like hocus-pocus and is likely to be rejected.

If you could convince a journal editor to publish two paper together in one volume with one focused on methodology and the other on an application it might work, however.

Answer (score 1):

For an *n* = 1, I have seen people create a model for a specific problem and then present the general model in a second paper.

For example, Dorazio published a new model as [part of one paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0121655) and then published a paper presenting the model as an R package in a [second paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/1755-0998.12735).

As for strategy, you're probably better off publishing the new methods paper first.
But, I've seen it done the other way too.

Comment: My personal experience is that this can work. During my PhD we published a paper using a methodology. The next month, in the same journal, we published an exposition of the methodology, including 6 pages of formulae. Your milage, of course, may vary.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily impossible to publish papers "out of order" but the problem you are going to encounter is that your applied paper will need to reference the information on the method, and if that has not already been published then the reviewer of the applied paper is likely to be unsatisfied.  One option here would be to publish the method paper as a preprint and cite the preprint in your applied paper so that you at least have some reliable reference to your method.  (This would require you to write the methods paper concurrently with the applied paper.)  You can then work more on your methods paper later and refine it into a form that is acceptable to a journal.

Answer (score 1):

For contrast, this is a very common model in molecular biology/bioinformatics. A new method will come out, and the first paper will be a demonstration that the method has produced  a result of biological interest.

There will then be a methods paper, in a journal like "Nature Methods", explaining the method/analysis.

See, for example, the BRIC-seq papers:

[Tani and Imamachi et al, "Identification of hundreds of novel UPF1 target transcripts by direct determination of whole transcriptome stability", 2012, RNA Biology 9:11, 1370–1379](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/epdf/10.4161/rna.22360?src=getftr)

[Imamachi and Tani et al, "BRIC-seq: A genome-wide approach for determining RNA stability in mammalian cells", 2014, Methods 67:1, 55-63](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1046202313002636?via%3Dihub#b0105)

There are often also papers that set out in detail a computational method that is used in a separate biology paper (one to a biology journal, one to a computational journal). The biology paper often comes out first, because no one want to let on about the method until they have results.

Comment: Interesting. I'm in a similar field and this is actually how things are working out! Its good to see that I'm not alone in this!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be much better to write the methods paper first as it will provide the reader's a reference for further reading of the method